# Popular methods for outlier detection (right skewed distribution)

Tags: outliers

What are the popular methods for outlier detection in univariate data, which do not assume normal distribution?

Comment: Many, many relevant questions on outliers here: have you consulted several? You need to have a specific new question to have much chance of a detailed answer. In any case, I wouldn't put much faith in popularity of methods any more than I judge newspapers by their circulation. Dropping presumed outliers just because they appear inconvenient is, I guess, one of the most popular methods, but arguably the worst of all.

Comment: One possibility is http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78063/replacing-outliers-with-mean/78067#78067 In that thread, as may happen here, the answers were wider than the question.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you should avoid trimming outliers in an ad hoc fashion and instead use nonparametric or robust alternatives.  A recent review with Monte Carlo studies can be found in [Bakker and Wicherts (2014)](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jelte_Wicherts/publication/261953191_Outlier_removal_sum_scores_and_the_inflation_of_the_type_I_error_rate_in_independent_samples_t_tests_The_power_of_alternatives_and_recommendations/links/02e7e538c6171d4003000000.pdf).  At least in psychology journals, Z-score cut-offs were most popular.  Of course, I wouldn't recommend that; the simulation studies in the same article demonstrate that Z-score cut-offs can inflate Type I error rates.

Although the review is focused on independent samples t-tests, most of their recommendations will apply more broadly. They concluded with the following recommendations:

> • Correct or delete erroneous values.
>
> • Based on prior research, it is not recommended to use Z scores
>   to identify outliers. We recommend methods that suffer less from
>   masking like the IQR or the MAD-median rule instead.
>
> • Decide on outlier handling before seeing the results of the
>   main analyses, and if possible, preregister the study at, for example,
>   the Open Science Framework (http://openscienceframework.org/).
>
> • If preregistration is not possible, report the outcomes both
>   with and without outliers or on the basis of alternative methods.
>
> • Report transparently about how outliers were handled.
>
> • Do not carelessly remove outliers as this increases the probability
>   of finding a false positive, especially when using a threshold
>   value of Z lower than 3 or when the data are skewed.
>
> • Use methods that are less influenced by outliers like nonparametric
>   or robust methods such as the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon
>   test and the Yuen-Welch test, or researchers may choose to conduct
>   bootstrapping (all without removing outliers).

References:

[Bakker, M., & Wicherts, J. M. (2014).](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jelte_Wicherts/publication/261953191_Outlier_removal_sum_scores_and_the_inflation_of_the_type_I_error_rate_in_independent_samples_t_tests_The_power_of_alternatives_and_recommendations/links/02e7e538c6171d4003000000.pdf) Outlier removal, sum scores, and the inflation of the type I error rate in independent samples t tests: The power of alternatives and recommendations. *Psychological Methods, 19*(3), 409-427.

Comment: This is good advice, although I would greatly widen the list of approaches worth considering. I note that it does not answer the question as it says precisely nothing about popularity. As I consider that a dubious criterion, I am happy to upvote.

Comment: @Nick Cox, good points.  I've edited the answer. It now makes clear that the cited article  focused mainly on outliers with independent samples t-tests (that's the reason they emphasize Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon and Yuen-Welch tests.)

Comment: @NickCox thanks for the link, it is quite useful. I have records of n individuals behavior expressed in seconds. I want to apply a clustering algorithm to identify some behavioral groups, however I found that some individuals did other behavioral activities in the recorded time, and therefore the distribution is rightly skewed. I believe that this can affect my conclusions and the whole analysis. Therefore I'm just trying to find a way how to reduce influence of such records.

Comment: You have a more specific question then. So either edit this question or (better, I think) start a new thread. However, I would advise expanding this outline greatly.